# Handle/select different Implementations of an interface during Building the project using Bazel Build

Tags: c++, build, bazel

I have two implementations of an interface in cpp and I want to choose one of the implementation each time while building (Bazel Build) the project and the generated executable application should be of same name each time.
My BUILD file looks like:

```
cc_library(
name = "printme1",
srcs = ["Firstimplementation.cpp"],
hdrs = ["source.h"],
)

cc_library(
name = "printme2",
srcs = ["Secondimplementation.cpp"],
hdrs = ["source.h"],
)

cc_binary(

name = "call",
srcs = ["main.cpp"],
deps = [
        ":printme1",
    ],

)

cc_binary(

name = "call2",
srcs = ["main.cpp"],
deps = [
        ":printme2",
    ],

)
```

With this BUILD file I am able to get two different results but the generated executable application is of different name. I am building it as follows:

`$ bazel build call`   ---> gives me execuatable with name **call** in Gen-bin folder

`$ bazel build call2`   ---> gives me execuatable with name **call2** in Gen-bin folder

What should I do to have same name in the end and I can call include every time my own choice implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [select](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select) together with a [config_setting](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#config_setting).
Should be something like this:

```
config_setting(
    name = "printme1",
    values = {
        "define": "p1",
    },
)

config_setting(
    name = "printme2",
    values = {
        "define": "p2",
    },
)

cc_library(
    name = "printme",
    srcs = select({":printme1" : ["Firstimplementation.cpp"],
                   ":printme2" : ["Secondimplementation.cpp"]}),
    hdrs = ["source.h"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "call",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = [
        ":printme",
    ])
```

In this case you need to define, when building your app:

```
bazel build --define p1 :call
```

Comment: I could not see the cc_binary which would be called during building the project. Secondly I am getting errors for this. But somehow your approach is correct as far as bazel option/function is concerned.

Thirdly what variable should be assigned the value during building?

I think **define_values** would work as follows:

`config_setting(

                name = "a_and_b",

                define_values = {

                    "a": "1",
                    "b": "2",
                })`

Comment: Ah yes, I had some errors in my code, which i have changed now. Note, that u need one `config_setting` per configuration (i.e. per implementation file --> if you have three different implementations you need 3 `config_settings` and so on). I have added the `cc_binary` in my previous answer. And i fixed the command for building the app (I previously had `--define printme1` but it needs to be the value you have stated as the `"define"` value: `--define p1`).